# Get connection string value from Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a test project, i need to get the connection string value in a test class

```
public class EmplyeesScenarios
{
    private readonly TestServer _testServer;
    private readonly AppDbContext _testService;

    public EmplyeesScenarios()
    {
        _testServer = TestServerFactory.CreateServer<TestsStartup>();
        var dbOption = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>()
                       .UseSqlServer("//here i need to put the same connection string of _testServer")
                       .Options;
        _testService = new AppDbContext(dbOption);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the service collection on your test host. For example:

```
var config = _testServer.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfigurationRoot>();
var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("Foo");
```

However, you should actually be using this for *all* your services, so instead of trying to new up your context at all, just do:

```
var context = _testServer.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
```

No connection string needed.

Comment: it says No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationRoot' has been registered

Comment: How is `TestsStartup` being setup? Ideally, that should either inherit from your `Startup` class in your SUT project or you should use that `Startup` class directly. If you're creating a totally custom `Startup` class just for testing, you're invalidating all your tests.

Comment: public class TestsStartup : Startup
============================
public TestsStartup(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration) { }

Comment: @ChrisPratt The web host will register `IConfiguration`, not `IConfigurationRoot`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your test server is set up properly, you should just resolve your database context from the server instance directly. Like this:

```
_testServer = TestServerFactory.CreateServer<TestsStartup>();

// create service scope and retrieve database context
using (var scope = _testServer.Host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppDbContext>();

    // ensure that the db is created for example
    await db.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

    // add test fixtures or whatever
}
```

Technically, you could also resolve the configuration from the test host and the read the connection string out of it but since you are doing an *integration test*, you should actually test the full integration and not deviate from the existing setup by creating your database context manually.